# IEEE ISBI referencing

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing

I am trying to reference as follows:

Search papers in google scholar, then click 'cite' and select BibTeX option.
Copy this code into a .bib file in latex.

I have downloaded a template for the paper from http://2020.biomedicalimaging.org/full-paper-instructions, where there is a `IEEEbib.bst` file. (bibliography style)

Call the following commands at the end of my paper:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{dong,mrf,davies,scheffler,bloch}
```

where my reference files are called `dong.bib`, `mrf.bib`, etc.

However when I do this none of the references materialise and I get this error message:

> There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about when and how the error message is generated. For sure, the error message doesn't sound like it is generated by BibTeX. For that matter, do you run BibTeX?

Comment: I am using overleaf - I am new to referencing so I am finding it all quite confusing

Comment: In that case, you really ought to address your query to the Overleaf Helpdesk. I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.